# What does the : mean in rails before a variable name?

Tags: ruby, symbols

For example, `:` symbol - I'm trying to work out what the `:` means, and how it differs, say, for example, from `@` and also from no symbol whatsoever.

If there's a guide that would be really helpful!

Comment: Did you try searching for "symbol"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a symbol, which is a Ruby language construct.

Symbols are similar to strings, but [this blog post](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/) explains the details.

`@` means an instance variable on the class: it's basically a variable that's shared among all methods on an instance of a class.  It has no relation to `:`.

Comment: Link is dead. Your answer only explains what `@` is. Not what a ruby symbol is :(

Answer (score 3):

`:` denotes that you are using a symbol.

`@` is an instance variable - basically a variable that is set once and can be used through a ruby process until it is done.

Plain old `variable_name` is a local variable and that variable is only good for as long as that method is called.

As for guides, you should read up on ruby basics or take a look at the something like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm)

Comment: What’s a symbol?

Answer (score 1):

@ is an ivar 
: is an symbol (think it like a COSTANT in C, but without any numerical value)

Answer (score 0):

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_symbols.html and http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm are 2 well written guides (second one might be a bit old, but most of it applies in Ruby 1.9 too).

You might also want to check the official documentation on Symbol at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html